# Case when using future data 'out of range value '

Tags: date, range

```
 select  
 sum(A.[usercount1]) as [2015-01]
,Sum(A.[usercount2]) as [2015-02]

from 
(select
startdate 
enddate
when '2015-01-31' > U.startdate and '2015-01-31' < U.enddate then     count(username)
 Else NULL
    End as 'usercount1'
   ,
    Case
  when '2015-02-31' > U.startdate and '2015-02-31' < U.enddate then     count(username)
 Else NULL
 End as 'usercount2' 


 FROM  U

   group by U.enddate, U.startdate, username, contract, u.email, region 

    )A
```

Getting Error: The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

How do I use dates that are in the future?

Answer (score 0):

So you have invalid dates for Feb.

I would look at EOMONTH (end of month) function https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213020.aspx

So you can just pass in the 1st of the month and SQL will work out the rest.